# How to bind custom context to Jersey request

Tags: java, jersey

I have a Jersey REST application with token-based user authentication. When a request comes in, a custom `RestContext` object gets created and added to the `ContainerRequestContext` as a property (via a filter that runs right after the request is received). This context manages user authorization (through roles) and access to other business logic. It's available in the resources to perform business logic. When the request is processed, the `RestContext` gets cleaned up in a second filter that executes at the very end of the pipeline.

This works fine although it requires two filters. I have been reading about the use of HK2 and the `InjectionResolver` and I was wondering if I could use injection to inject this `RestContext` in my resources and other filters (for example I have a filter that creates a `SecurityContext` from the `RestContext`) but I couldn't find an answer. In general, how do I inject an object per request that depends on the request context? Is this even possible? Is there an easier way to do it, e.g., using `@Context`?

**EDIT**: As pointed out, I'm basically trying to inject in my resources a custom class along the lines of [the documentation](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/ioc.html). However, I don't seem to be able to correctly register my `AbstractBinder` to bind the injection of my class. I get the following:

```
org.glassfish.hk2.api.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: There was no object available for injection at Injectee(requiredType=RestContext,parent=RestContextFilter,qualifiers={}),position=0,optional=false,self=false,unqualified=null,1435496015)
```

**EDIT** 2: I managed to make some slight progress. I create my config in the following way:

```
new ResourceConfig(allResources())
  .packages(packagesToScan())
  .registerInstances(new RestContextBinder());
```

since the documentation clearly states that injection of binders is [not supported via class but via instance](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/2.6/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/server/ResourceConfig.html#registerClasses%28java.lang.Class...%29).

However I am now getting this:

```
A MultiException has 3 exceptions.  They are:
1. java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not inside a request scope.
2. java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: While attempting to resolve the dependencies of my.package.RestContextFilter errors were found
3. java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to perform operation: resolve on my.package.RestContextFilter
```

The RestContext is `@Inject`-ed in a request/response filter. It's then used to create a `SecurityContext` and set it in the `ContainerRequestContext` and it's cleaned up in the response filter. Aren't response filter request scoped? Why am I getting the error?

Comment: I am not sure about the proper way to do this within Jersey.  That being said, I think if you could find the Jersey implementation of the Context you could write your own InjectionResolver that injects the Jersey one.  If you make your Context have a higher priority than the Jersey injection resolver it will get chosen as the resolver before the Jersey one.  You can then enhance the Jersey resolver all you want, and when you don't want you can simply call the Jersey context methods as the fallback method

Comment: Wow, that sounds hacky! I think I'll stick with this approach until I find something a little more mainstream. It's not really worth the effort.

Comment: I may be misunderstanding your question, but I believe you want to do something like. `bind(RestContext.class).in(RequestScoped.class)` in your config. This will allow you to do `@Inject RestContext ctx;` and ensure that only one instance lives per request. You can inject it into your filter and set the necessary info, and then inject it everywhere else as needed. You do not need to set anything on the `ContainerRequestContext`, just inject your `RestContext`. Also you don't need to clean up anything. Is this what you were looking for? If so I can add it as an answer.

Comment: @Alden this sounds just like what I need. Can this be done through annotations instead of config? And how is it cleaned up? I have a `close()` method in my RestContext that needs to get called after the REST method has been executed. How does that get bound? Finally, where is this stuff in the docs? I could not find it anywhere! Thanks

Comment: @GiovanniBotta I just posted an answer outlining my thoughts. I don't know where these things are in the docs, sorry! I banged my head against Jersey for a long time to get stuff like this working.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**UPDATE** now that Jersey 2.7 is out, the solution is simpler.

It sounds like you want a `RequestScoped` binding. Here is how you might set things up with Jersey 2.7:

You will need a request filter, and because `RestContext` will be `RequestScoped`, you can inject a provider into your filter, set some properties on it, and know they will be available for the remainder of the request.

```
@Priority(Priorities.AUTHORIZATION) // filter deals with roles, comes after AUTHENTICATION
public class RestContextFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter
{
    // you need to inject a provider, rather than the class directly
    // because this filter is instantiated before the request scope is ready
    private Provider<RestContext> rcProvider;

    @Inject
    public RestContextFilter(Provider<RestContext> rcProvider)
    {
        this.rcProvider = rcProvider;
    }

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) throws IOException
    {
        // now you're in a request scope and can get your context
        RestContext rc = rcProvider.get();

        // set some properties on rc here (current user or roles or whatever)
    }
}
```

You need to register the filter and bind `RestContext` in your `ResourceConfig` using an HK2 binding:

```
public class MyResourceConfig extends ResourceConfig
{
    public MyResourceConfig()
    {
        register(RestContextFilter.class);

        register(new AbstractBinder()
        {
            @Override
            protected void configure()
            {
                bindFactory(new Factory<RestContext>()
                {
                    @Override
                    public RestContext provide()
                    {
                        return new RestContext();
                    }

                    // this will get called at the end of the request
                    // allowing you to close your request scoped object
                    @Override
                    public void dispose(RestContext instance)
                    {
                        instance.close();
                    }
                }, RequestScoped.class).to(RestContext.class).in(RequestScoped.class);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Then you can inject `RestContext` in your resources, and it will have all of the info set up by your filter. For example:

```
@Path("/my/path")
public class MyResource
{
    private RestContext rc;

    @Inject
    public MyResource(RestContext rc)
    {
        this.rc = rc;
    }

    @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public void upload(MyPostObj data)
    {
        // do stuff here, and rc is all set up
    }
}
```

I tend to prefer constructor injection over field injection because I think it makes your dependencies more obvious for other developers reading your code. Also sorry if my style of braces annoys you, I come from the wonderful world of .NET :).

Comment: Looks awesome. Will try it and get back.

Comment: So if I have a constructor `RestContext(ContainerRequestContext)` can I just annotate it with `@Inject` to have Jersey inject the request context at creation time?

Comment: Actually I'm getting: `org.glassfish.hk2.api.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: There was no object available for injection at Injectee(requiredType=RestContext,parent=RestContextFilter,qualifiers={}),position=0,optional=false,self=false,unqualified=null,1983762179)`. Did my binding not work? I added a `RestContextBinder.class` to the list of classes in the constructor of my `ResourceConfig` object. Is that not going to work?

Comment: What is `RestContextBinder`? Is that your filter or does that extend `AbstractBinder` and configure the `RestContext` binding? If it's the latter than that should work fine. If `RestContext` needs access to `ContainerRequestContext` you can either set it via a property (rather than the constructor) in the `filter` method, or I think you can constructor inject it like this: `@Inject public RestContext(@Context ContainerRequestContext)`. I'm not sure about that though. I would need to see your code to help you out more. Maybe post a gist?

Comment: Yes it is an `AbstractBinder` and no it does not work. I tried adding a parameterless constructor to `RestContext` but I still get the same exception.

Comment: Aha, I think I know the problem! Change it to: `bind(RestContext.class).to(RestContext.class).in(RequestScoped.class);`. I use Guice instead of HK2, and when binding a class to itself using Guice you cannot include the "to" part or it breaks. Looks like HK2 requires it though. I just updated my answer.

Comment: I'm trying to follow the docs: https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/ioc.html with not much luck either.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49245/discussion-between-alden-and-giovanni-botta)

Comment: Accepted although I haven't tested it yet.

Comment: BTW does this work with Jersey 2.6? Also, how can I make sure that my `close()` method executes __after__ the entity is serialized?

Comment: No it doesn't work in 2.6, see [this revision](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/22228988/4) for the 2.6 version

Comment: Ouch it looks like this will always run _before_ the entity gets serialized. That won't work for me because the `close()` method closes the Hibernate session and the proxy will throw on lazy loading relations. This is giving me a headache!

Comment: BTW I know the solution is to handle DB transactions differently but this is a legacy app...